# Cannot pass BAT parameters to variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, command-line, parameters

I have a problem with passing parameters to variables in BAT file:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 

if "%5" NEQ "" ( 
echo [%5][%6] //it displays normal parameters like 10 and 30 
set /a sstart=%~5 // was testing without /a, without ~, with $, in all combinations 
set /a sstop=%~6 
echo [%sstart%][%sstop%] // parameters are empty 
set sekstart=--start-at duration:%sstart% 
set /a sekstopr=%sstop% - %sstart% 
set sekstop=--stop-at duration:%sekstopr% 
echo Start: %sstart% Stop: %sekstop% 
)
```

This is for encoding in Handbrake: 
https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide

Comment: You've got an [delayed expansion problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if "%5" NEQ "" (
```

to

```
if "%5" == "" goto skip
```